# VSCode autocomplete names for required python kwonlyargs

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a  codebase with a lot of functions/methods like this (usually more parameters since it ranks around a message protocol with many fields which have no default):

```
def method(self, *, flag1: bool, message: str, anotherArg: EnumType) -> SomeType:
    ...
```

is there any VSCode extension, which autocompletes calls to these methods with the names of the keyword only args filled in? i.e. after typing `MyClass.m` i would like autocompletion to offer me this:

```
MyClass.method(flag1=, message=,anotherArg=)
```

or even:

```
MyClass.method(flag1=, message="",anotherArg=EnumType.)
```

Bonus question: I know that pylance offers inlay hints for call argument names, can it (or something else) show hints for parameter types too? (I have not found an option)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**Python**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension provides Intellisense, you can use the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to get the following effects

[image]

If you can use [**GitHub Copilot**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=GitHub.copilot), and enable the following setting:

```
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
```

you will get something like this (*Use the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to accept shaded section suggestions*)

[image]